# Why I can not train Matrix Factorization model with BigQuery even though I have purchased flex slots?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am strugguling for more than two weeks with BigQuery. All the docs are just ad ertizing the product, without any help.

First thing first, I dont want to use Enterprise Edition or Enterprise Plus Edition. I am currently evaluating BigQuery as a possible solution to my machine learning problem. That is, right now I am ate the stage of developing proof of conept.

As written on the docs:

> Note: Matrix factorization models are only available to flat-rate
> customers or customers with reservations. On-demand customers are
> encouraged to use flex slots to use matrix factorization.

That is, me as a regular customer (not one who purchased Enterprice or Enterprice Plus editions) have to by flex slots and then set up a reservation with it?

I bought 100 flex slots, with the idea just to see how it works and if it will be helpful for my case.

Then I created a reservation from the `create reservation` page. From the `Edition` dropdown I had 3 options: `Standard`, `Enterprise` and `Enterprise Plus`.

As far as I understand, `Standard` is the only option which I can use for my proof of a concept, that is, I can set up a `Standard` reservation, run the SQL query, see if the model works for me, and then delete the reservation. I did not choose `Enerprice` or `Enterprise Plus` because they are billed annually which obviously I dont want.

After I  created the reservation, I run the SQL query which is from the official tutorial [page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigqueryml-mf-explicit-tutorial#explicit-model)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL bqml_tutorial.my_explicit_mf_model
OPTIONS
  (model_type='matrix_factorization',
   user_col='user_id',
   item_col='item_id',
   l2_reg=9.83,
   num_factors=34) AS
SELECT
  user_id,
  item_id,
  rating
FROM movielens.movielens_1m
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Training Matrix Factorization models is not available for on-demand usage. To train, please set up a reservation (flex or regular) based on instructions in BigQuery public docs.
```

What I am doing wrong? I am not supposed to buy something which will be billed annually so I just run a query from the official docs, am I? How am I supposed to test the product, without getting into an annual contract? I want just to test that one query and pay for that one query only, not to buy one year contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the reservation, allow your project to use the reservation.
Usually, it's create slots, reserve, assign.

```
bq mk --reservation_assignment \
      --reservation_id=${PROJECT}:${LOCATION}.${RESERVATION} \
      --job_type=QUERY --assignee_type=PROJECT \
      --assignee_id=${PROJECT}
```

For more info: [Using BigQuery Flex Slots to run machine learning workloads more efficiently](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-bigquery-flex-slots-to-run-machine-learning-workloads-more-efficiently-7fc7f400f7a7)